# Uninstall Angular.js completely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, npm, frameworks

Is it safe to just delete all angular files and folders?
Tried to find the answer, but there's nothing I could find about uninstalling angular.

Comment: Its just scripts. Nothing ever gets installed anywhere. Just delete the files.

Comment: And why do you want to do so? If you are using angular framework then you surely required to have those dependencies for your app. Then there is no point to delete them.

Comment: @Jai long story short: I had it for ages, but never worked with it. I know what you mean though ;)

Comment: search your computer all files conntaining `angular` and delete it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the files but don't forget to search all files containing
`"/your/angular/path"`.